# How do i save checkboxes ticked for each user account?

Tags: php

I'm a very beginner programmer and doing a project currently where i have multiple checkboxes you can check after creating your account. Sadly, the account doesn't know how to remember the boxes the user checked on his account. So the question is simple : how do i make it so that the user's choices are registered to his account?

Here is the index.php :

```
<?php 
session_start(); 

if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
  header('location: login.php');
}
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
session_destroy();
unset($_SESSION['username']);
header("location: login.php");
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "stylehome.css">
    <title>FFBE Unit Collection</title>
</head>


<body>

<header>
    <h1>FFBE Unit Collection</h1>

</header>

<div class="content">
<!-- notification message -->
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['success'])) : ?>
  <div class="error success" >
    <h3>
      <?php 
        echo $_SESSION['success']; 
        unset($_SESSION['success']);
      ?>
    </h3>
  </div>
<?php endif ?>

<!-- logged in user information -->
<?php  if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) : ?>
    <p>Welcome <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></strong></p>
    <p> <a href="index.php?logout='1'" style="color: red;">Logout</a>       </p>
<?php endif ?>
</div>

<br><br>

     <!--Here starts the 5 star bases-->

    <img src="ressources/fivestar.png" class="star"/>
    <br>
    <div id="rainbow">

    <input type="checkbox" name="units" id="lightning">
    <label for="lightning">
    <img src="units/lightning.png"/>  
    </label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="units" id="delita">
    <label for="delita">
    <img src="units/delita.png"/>  
    </label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="units" id="ramza">
    <label for="ramza">
    <img src="units/ramza.png"/>  
    </label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="units" id="darkknightcecil">
    <label for="darkknightcecil">
    <img src="units/darkknightcecil.png"/>  
    </label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="units" id="luneth">
    <label for="luneth">
    <img src="units/luneth.png"/>  
    </label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="units" id="gilgamesh">
    <label for="gilgamesh">
    <img src="units/gilgamesh.png"/>  
    </label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="units" id="noctis">
    <label for="noctis">
    <img src="units/noctis.png"/>  
    </label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="units" id="darkfina">
    <label for="darkfina">
    <img src="units/darkfina.png"/>  
    </label>



    </div>





<br/>
<footer>





</footer>
```

And here is the server.php :

```
<?php
session_start();

// variable declaration
$username = "";
$errors = array(); 
$_SESSION['success'] = "";

// connect to database
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration');

    // REGISTER USER
if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
 // receive all input values from the form
 $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
 $password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_1']);
 $password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_2']);

 // form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled
 if (empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "Username is required"); }
 if (empty($password_1)) { array_push($errors, "Password is required"); }
 if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
   array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");
 }

 // register user if there are no errors in the form
 if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password_1);//encrypt the password before saving in    the database
    $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) 
          VALUES('$username', '$password')";
    mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
header('location: index.php');
     }

  }


  // LOGIN USER
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
   $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
   $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

 if (empty($username)) {
   array_push($errors, "Username is required");
   }
 if (empty($password)) {
   array_push($errors, "Password is required");
 }

 if (count($errors) == 0) {
$password = md5($password);
   $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND   password='$password'";
$results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
  $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
  $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
  header('location: index.php');
}else {
    array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
    }
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: Post your code please. The question is too broad otherwise.

Comment: hello, sorry for the trouble, added two main codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Checkboxes` as opposed to `radio buttons` use different `names` unless they belong to a `checkbox group` in which case they would have the same names with `[]` at the end like this `name="chkbx1[]"`. The receiving `PHP` file then queries for the name of the `checkbox` to see if it exists withing the `$_POST` or `$_GET` variable. If it does it means it was `checked`. If it doesn't it means it was `unchecked`.

The `id` tag has nothing to do with `PHP`. It's for `client side` programming purposes only. For `sever side` (in this case `PHP`) refer to the `name` tag for identification.

This is code from `<div> rainbow`:

Note: I changed all checkboxes names to match their ids

```html
<form action="pathToYourPHPfile/example.php" method="POST">
  <table cellspacing="15">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="lightning"><img src="units/lightning.png"/></label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="lightning" id="lightning">
    </td>
    <td>
      <label for="delita"><img src="units/delita.png"/></label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="delita" id="delita">
    </td>
    <td>
      <label for="ramza"><img src="units/ramza.png"/></label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="ramza" id="ramza">
    </td>
    <td>
      <label for="darkknightcecil"><img src="units/darkknightcecil.png"/></label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="darkknightcecil" id="darkknightcecil">
    </td>
    <td>
      <label for="luneth"><img src="units/luneth.png"/></label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="luneth" id="luneth">
    </td>
    <td>
      <label for="gilgamesh"><img src="units/gilgamesh.png"/></label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="gilgamesh" id="gilgamesh">
    </td>
    <td>
      <label for="noctis"><img src="units/noctis.png"/></label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="noctis" id="noctis">
    </td>
    <td>   
      <label for="darkfina"><img src="units/darkfina.png"/></label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="darkfina" id="darkfina">
    </td>
   <tr>
  </table>

  <input type="submit" value="click Me To Submit">
</form>
```

And this would be a valid query to see if a checkbox was checked from withing the receiving `PHP` file `example.php`:

```
<?php
    // an array of possible checkbox names
    $myCheckBoxArray = array("lightning", "delita", "ramza", "darkknightcecil", "luneth", "gilgamesh", "noctis", "darkfina");

    // connect to the database
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', ...  // database connection 

    // go through the list of checkbox names and check if checked
    for($i=0; $i<count($myCheckBoxArray); $i++)
    {
        // if its set that means it was checked. An example is isset($_POST['delita'])
        if( isset( $_POST[$myCheckBoxArray[$i]] ) )
        {
            echo $myCheckBoxArray[$i].' is set<br/>';

            // write to database
            mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO tableName (user, chose) VALUES ('batman', '".$myCheckBoxArray[$i]."')");
        }
        else
        {
            echo $myCheckBoxArray[$i].' is not set<br/>';
            // Do something
        }
    }
?>
```

And create an example table in MySQL like this:

```
create table `tableName`
(
   `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `user` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
   `chose` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wasn't aware. As i understand it, i have to make a table with each "name" being called out in a column? This part is still difficult to me. I want that each user account remembers the boxes the said user checked.

Comment: @Dreamy I have edited to show you a `table` example. I put it all in two columns just so it can fit here in the snippet. The `table` and `button` must be wrapped inside a `form` to be sent unless you are using `javascript`, from what you have pasted you are not.

Comment: Thanks for the modifications, sadly i'm completely lost here more than before and i have no idea what to set in the database as i have never used one before (only today for account making). When i pasted the code it went from this (before) https://puu.sh/yMNxW/79113d93df.png to this (after) : https://puu.sh/yMOjq/92b73e3a49.png   the css doesn't work on the checkboxes anymore so they aren't grayed and thus cannot be checked/unchecked. In all of that, i still have no clue how to register the checked informations in the database, maybe this is too big for me sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @Dreamy I edited the `HTML` to give an `inline table`. I also edited the `PHP example file` with more comments and a `database connection and insertion example`. You can just copy all the `PHP` I wrote and paste it into `your PHP file` except the connection `mysqli_connect('localhost', ...`, you already have one so you don't need another.

Comment: @Dreamy I also added an example on how to `create a table in MySQL`. It's an `example table` to fit the `example PHP file`. It's at the bottom of all the code.

Comment: Thank you for the edits, sadly nothing works out... the table and checkboxes are defective, the submit button doesn't send anything in the database (the newly created table) and now for some reason the logout function creates an error. I have no idea how to fix this and don't want to take more of your time.

Comment: @Dreamy I found a typo, copy this line of code again like this `mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO tableName ('user', 'chose') VALUES ('batman', '".$myCheckBoxArray[$i]."')");`. It was missing some apostrophes `""`. Tell me if it works.

Comment: @Dreamy Oh, and its better to use `<input type="radio" ... ` if you are expecting only `one value`. If you are expecting `multiple values` then `radio` is not good.

Comment: It says "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'for' (T_FOR) in C:\xampp\htdocs\ffbe\submit.php on line 9"  when i click the button. I renamed "example" to "submit" (and made sure it was the case in the html). Here are some screenshots : https://puu.sh/yMPB6/010acf16c0.png and https://puu.sh/yMPBv/6b881811c9.png and https://puu.sh/yMPC6/26fc1d5085.png

Comment: @Dreamy Did you also copy this line of code into your file? `$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', ...  // database connection ` If you did then erase it as you already have a connection in the file at the top. Or copy and paste `your line` of code containing the real parameters and erase mine.

Comment: Just to make sure, does the PHP code go in my "server.php" code i posted or a new file (you quoted exemple.php) ? I tried both, and neither is working, they don't register anything in the database at least. When i click the button, it takes me to this : https://puu.sh/yMPLS/07e67d4ee1.png  but that's it, it doesn't remember it afterwards.

Comment: @Dreamy Ok, that is good. That means you are landing on the `example page` and the `example page` is correctly checking the checkboxes. Now `erase my line of code`  in the `example file` and `copy/paste your line of code from the server PHP` file containing the `same information` into the `example file` in the same location where mine was written, save the changes and try again. It should work now. This line of code `$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', ...  // database connection `, replace with yours `$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration');`

Comment: Do you mean : $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration'); ?  I did but still nothing added in the database...  Here is my code : https://puu.sh/yMPY2/be85201957.png

What is the value "batman" for?

Comment: @Dreamy `MySQL` is `case sensitive`, replace this `tablename` with this `tableName` in `mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO tableName ('user', 'chose') VALUES ('batman', '".$myCheckBoxArray[$i]."')");` For some reason you have a lower case `n` there.

Comment: Still the same, not working. I changed the N to n before because it is in lower case in the database https://puu.sh/yMQ61/3428e30b0f.png and thought it would help. But sadly in both cases N or n, it still doesn't send a thing. Sorry for the trouble, i have no clue what is wrong. Is it perhaps related to the database itself?

Comment: @Dreamy Ok. I found the error at last. Leave the lower case n since it is like that in the database. Change this `('user', 'chose')` to this `(user, chose)` without the apostrophes `'` in `mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO tableName ('user', 'chose') VALUES ('batman', '".$myCheckBoxArray[$i]."')");`

Comment: ok so it DID send this time something here : https://puu.sh/yMQh7/bc6dabe58b.png

BUT when i come back to index.php everything is unchecked, why? Keep in mind that i am logged on a specific account and that account can have different boxes checked than another account (user) etc... anyway, everything is unchecked even if the database has something in it. The database says the user "batman" altough that user doesn't exist. I have a table for all registered users already, how do i make the link?

Comment: @Dreamy Alright! You got it working! When you go back you can't see the change because you need to query for that on the client side if you want to see the change. I think I solved your initial question so please mark my answer as accepted and you can give me an upvote if you found my answer useful. If you have any problems just ping me. I got to go now (to sleep - its 6am - I'm in Europe currently :) ), but will be back tomorrow. Peace

Comment: Well it did help for sure thanks, but it's still not solving the question "for each user account", in hope that you can help me later about that. Thanks for the help, good night and take care. (I'm in France so yea it's very late!)

Comment: @Dreamy No problem, I will help you out with that tomorrow. It's a couple more lines of code to set it all up. Peace

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161901/discussion-between-ivan86-and-dreamy).

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming, your project has a database to store registered users information. If so, then create a table in the database. On that table, create one column for each options that a user can checked, alone with a column for user id as foreign key. Then set a value (typically 1) to each of the column for a specific user id to that table to remember which options the user checked.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. Yes i'm using a database which contains only a users table so far (with id, username and password). I'll try and see if i can do your steps.

Comment: You can also extend the table with multiple columns, each for one check box. Initially the value for all these new columns will be empty or 0. Then, whatever checkboxex will be selected, put 1 for the respective columns

Comment: May I know, why someone dislike this solution?

Comment: (i didn't dislike, just in case) Sorry if i'm being a bit slow on this, just have a few questions since i'm learning on how to use a database. My page will have probably over 100 checkboxes (they're images) but they all have the same purpose and name (their ID is different tho), do i need to create a column for each checkbox ID i presume? Also, i don't know how to setup that last column with the foreign key. Thanks.

Comment: 100 checkbox is really big and do not seems to me practical that a user will go through 100 options and check them as required. However, if that is a case that cannot be avoided, then let me know how many (in percentage) of these check boxes are expected to be check for an average user. 
(if you like the solution, you can upvote it to remove the -1 tag)

Comment: Maybe i'm approaching this the wrong way, but i'm making a user collection for a game. The user can "check" each character to show that he has it. I use checkboxes so that users can check each character they have and i want the database to register each user's collection. Some users will probably have over 70% of the checkboxes checked, as there are lots of characters in the game. (I tried upvoting but site says since my account is new it doesn't show public).

https://puu.sh/yMNxW/79113d93df.png

Here is a sample, the grayed out checkboxes are unchecked of course.

Comment: if you think your user have 70% check box to be checked, then it is better to have 100 column. Alternatively, you can create another table and save one row per check box in that table, with user_id as foreign key.